# TYPO3 (8.7.10) navigating back to previous page, remembering posted values

Tags: php, post, search, typo3, fluid

I have created a search form in TYPO3. The user can filter results by selecting options in a form. the form is handled using the FLUID form line as follows:

```
<f:form method="POST" action="list" name="eventsearch">
```

...this works correctly (and I noticed the cHash at the end of the URL when submitting)

When the user finds the item they want they can click on it which takes them to another page. On that page there is a back button which directs them back to the search page, but all the filtered variables are lost and they are sent back to the first search page. This is to be expected, but is there any way it can retain this information?

I have tried passing through the url reference (with has key), but that didn't work. I also tried classic window.history.back() but as the search form uses POST they would have to refresh the screen again. I have also tried swapping my form post to GET, but I get an error regarding an incorrect cHash.

I'm assuming there is a way, as the FLUID pagination buttons can retain the information even though they appear to be using GET.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the form data into the session of the user. This way they can be restored from session regardless from where the user navigates back to the form.
This would mean, if you have a `showFormAction` and a `showResultsAction` you need to store the form data in the `showResultsAction` as follows:

```
public function showResultsAction(FormData $formData)
{
    $this->storeInSession($formData);
    // do something with the formData here
}

protected function storeInSession(FormData $formData)
{
    if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']) {
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->setAndSaveSessionData('tx_myext_formdata',$formData);
    } elseif($GLOBALS['BE_USER']) {
        $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->setAndSaveSessionData('tx_myext_formdata',$formData);
    }
}
```

You are going to fetch the form data on the users next visit of `showFormAction` like this:

```
public function showFormAction(FormData $formData = NULL)
{
    if ($formData === NULL) {
        $formData = $this->getSessionData();
    }
    $this->view->assign('formData', $formData);
    // do more stuff for the form here
}

protected function getSessionData() 
{
    $formData = NULL;
    if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']) {
        $formData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getSessionData('tx_myext_formdata');
    } elseif ($GLOBALS['BE_USER']) {
        $formData = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->getSessionData('tx_myext_formdata');
    }
    return $formData;
}
```

And give the formData to your form view helper `<f:form method="POST" action="list" name="formData" object="{formData}">`.

FormData in this example is a DTO that is storing the forms individual fields as properties, like a model but not persisted into a database table like the AbstractEntities. This way it is easier to give the restored values back to the form, because the form is prefilling its fields automatically with values from the DTO.
For example if you have a field `<f:form.textfield name="somefield" />` in your form, you give the FormData DTO the property `property $somefield = '';`, a getter and a setter and change the view helper to become `<f:form.textfield property="somefield" />` and the form will handle the prefilling all by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but my version (8.7.10) didn't like the use of those sessiondata functions. I did some research and found a similar sessino "setKey" and "getKey" which does the trick nicely :). I'll post the full update below.

Answer (score 0):

as [@Kevin Ditscheid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596832/kevin-ditscheid) pointed out, I could save my form data as session data. Using 8.7.10 I used the following function to store my data:

`$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey("ses","some_variable_name",$data);`

...which can be retrieved like so:

`$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey("ses","some_variable_name");`

When a user navigates back from another page via a button, I ensure a variable "returned=1" is included in the URL. My controller class looks for this variable and if found, returns the form post data from my session data.